# iPhone 3G crash on pushViewController

Tags: crash, pushviewcontroller, iphone-3g

I have pushing ViewController with usual way:

```
SomeViewController *newViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
newViewController.username = self.username;
[self.navigationController newViewController animated:YES];
[newViewController release];
```

This code works great on iPhone 4/4S. But when I've tested it on iPhone 3G: when I go back in newViewController app crashes. Only on iPhone 3G. But if I comment [newViewController release]; line there is no any problems.

SomeViewController doesn't have viewDidUnload method and dealloc only consist some releases of properties and [super dealloc];

What it can be?